# Free monads for recursive arithmetic expressions in Scala cats

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I am trying to define a simple arithmetic expressions evaluator using the [Scala cats](http://typelevel.org/cats/) library and following the [tutorial doc](http://typelevel.org/cats/tut/freemonad.html).

The goal is to define the DSL in a modular way combining integer values and additions which could be defined separately.

I have the following code:

```
package examples
import cats._
import cats.data._
import cats.free._
import cats.free.Free._
import scala.language.higherKinds

object FreeExpr {

  sealed trait ValueF[A]
  case class IntValue(n: Int) extends ValueF[Int]

  class Value[F[_]](implicit I: Inject[ValueF, F]) {
    def intVal(n:Int): Free[F,Int] = inject[ValueF,F](IntValue(n))
  }

  object Value {
    implicit def value[F[_]](implicit I: Inject[ValueF,F]): Value[F] = new Value[F]
  }

  sealed trait ArithF[A]
  case class Add[A](x: A, y: A) extends ArithF[A]

  class Arith[F[_]](implicit I: Inject[ArithF, F]) {
   def add[A](x: A, y: A) : Free[F,A] =
     Free.inject[ArithF,F](Add(x,y))
  }

  object Arith {
    implicit def arith[F[_]](implicit I: Inject[ArithF,F]): Arith[F] = new Arith[F]
  }

  type Expr[A] = Coproduct[ArithF, ValueF, A]
  type Result[A] = Id[A]

  object ArithId  extends (ArithF ~> Result) {
    def apply[A](fa: ArithF[A]) = fa match {
      case Add(x,y) => ??? // for { m <- x; n <- y } yield (m + n)
    }
  }

  object ValueId extends (ValueF ~> Result) {
    def apply[A](fa: ValueF[A]) = fa match {
      case IntValue(n) => Monad[Id].pure(n)
    }
  }

  val interpreter: Expr ~> Result = ArithId or ValueId

  def expr1(implicit value : Value[Expr],
                     arith : Arith[Expr]): Free[Expr, Int] = {
    import value._, arith._
    for {
      n <- intVal(2)
      m <- add(n, n)
    } yield m
   }

  lazy val run1 = expr1.foldMap(interpreter)

}
```

The previous code compiles because I commented the definition of "apply" for the Add case. I initially thought the solution was the code that is commented, but the compiler returns:

```
[error] ...FreeExpr.scala:40: value flatMap is not a member of type parameter A
[error]       case Add(x,y) => for { m <- x; n <- y } yield (m + n)
[error]                                   ^
```

Do you know what do I need to change in the code to define the DSL and the interpreter in a modular way?

Comment: Well type parameter A should be a Monad in order to be able to flatMap on it. `fa: ArithF[A]` does not enforce it... I am not sure about the resolution as I am not so familiar with FreeMonads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the result type of `Add` was too general and in the `case Add(x,y) => ...` the values `x` and `y` had type `A` instead of `M[A]`.

I found two possible solutions.

One is to change the definition of `Add` to be `case class Add(x:Int,y:Int)` and the definition of the interpreter to be

```
object ArithId  extends (ArithF ~> Result) {
    def apply[A](fa: ArithF[A]) = fa match {
      case Add(x,y) => x + y
    }
}
```

I have added this solution to this gist: [FreeExprInt.scala](https://gist.github.com/labra/97dbe0969ecf4b51f80d803c76ad13c9)

One problem of the previous solution is that the result type is fixed to be an `Int` and it may be more interesting that it could be, at least a `Semigroup`.

I tried to define it using `case class Add[A: Semigroup](x: A, y: A)` but it seems that the compiler has some problems to treat second implicit parameters lists.

A possible workaround is to add the evidence explicitly. I added this solution to another gist: [FreeExprExplicit.scala](https://gist.github.com/labra/8ab7d830775ae7b7854787eb687a173f)

Although both solutions work, I am not quite satisfied by them as I would prefer a more generic solution where the result type could be any `A`.

I was suggested to take a look to the tagless final style ([Alternatives to GADTs](https://pchiusano.github.io/2014-05-20/scala-gadts.html)) but I didn't implement it yet.